# How to handle nested firebase queries and to update ionic view asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I was just wondering if someone could help me with an issue I'm having in my Ionic app.

I'm having trouble getting my head around nested firebase queries and being able to update the ionic view asynchronously. I'm not using angularfire or anything like that.

My database structure is the following...

```
    "posts" : {
      "-KguJ95gTreWH5AT5lQ1" : {
       "category" : "Example",
       "description" : "This is a test description!!!",
       "userID" : "SeMpRKxczcSCFpnkVDTU2pxCDV12"
      },
      "-Kh--WhNsWAXqs1jLfXu" : {
       "category" : "Example 2",
       "description" : "Test description .....",
       "userID" : "SeMpRKxczcSCFpnkVDTU2pxCDV12"
      }
   },
   "user-posts" : {
     "SeMpRKxczcSCFpnkVDTU2pxCDV12" : { // User ID
       "-KguJ95gTreWH5AT5lQ1" : { // Post
         "category" : "Example",
         "description" : "This is a test description!!!",
         "userID" : "SeMpRKxczcSCFpnkVDTU2pxCDV12"
       },
       "-Kh--WhNsWAXqs1jLfXu" : { // Post
         "category" : "Example 2",
         "description" : "Test description .....",
         "userID" : "SeMpRKxczcSCFpnkVDTU2pxCDV12"
       }
     }
   }
```

And my call to the database is the following...

```
    const posts: Post[] = [];
this.database.ref('posts').orderByChild('category').equalTo(this.category.name).once('value')
  .then(
    (posts) => {
      //console.log(posts.val());
      posts.forEach(function(childPost) {
        var post = childPost.val();
        var user = {};

        firebase.database().ref('users/'+post.userID).on('value', function(snapshot){
            user = snapshot.val();
            // console.log(user);
        });

        var newPost = new Post(childPost.key, post.category, post.description, user );
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(newPost));
        posts.push(newPost);
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
```

The problem I'm having is that my view is rendered before the data from the second query is resolved. I have to leave the view and re-enter for the change detection to update my view.

I've read about things such as nested observables etc, but that just seems like overkill for what I'm trying to do ( Or I may be wrong ). Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: can you show your UI code also?